# Windows 7 Reading Proper Disk Usage Statistics on Mounted Volumes

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I'm running Windows 7 with 2 x 1.5 TBYTE Drives.  The second internal drive is setup as a mounted volume as C:\Archives

Clicking computer icon in Windows Explorer, it only shows capacity stats for C: and Not C:\Archives

Also, the usage stats that do show for C: show to be 100% capacity red - yet the system runs fine.  No warnings.

Can someone explain this?  I do have a lot of stuff on the c: drive, but I'm sure its not 1.5 TB worth and C:\Archives hardly has anything it.

Comment: How can you have 2 C: drives?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to verify the permissions of folder `C:\Archives`?
Try to reapply the Admin permissions to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this free graphical tool to see your disk usage: [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/)